# (readObject + readresolve ) read as pointer

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I want to read an object from file using `ObjectInputStream`.
Here is what the `readObject` method looks like inside:

```
public void readObject(ObjectInputStream inbos) throws IOException {
    try {
        GameModel gm =  (GameModel) inbos.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameDeserializer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameDeserializer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }           
}
```

My `GameModel` class has a `readResolve` method. `GameModel` class is also a singleton.

```
public Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
    System.out.println("At read resolve method ");
    GameModel themodel = getGameModel();

    System.out.println("Reading the file : " + themodel.toString() + themodel );
    return themodel;
}
```

The problem is it is not reading the object right.
It is reading it as a pointer.
I need help please.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "reading it as a pointer"?

Comment: Another thing, is that readObject() the GameModel's readObject? if so, remove it.

Comment: (snapshotpattern.GameModel@506c0a14snapshotpattern.GameModel@506c0a14 ) That's the output I get when I read the file.

Comment: @missh That's just the result of calling toString() on the object, twice, for some reason. It is not evidence of any kind for 'as a pointer', which is meaningless in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of [`readResolve()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a5903) will replace whatever you had written in the stream with the current singleton, so no data from the stream is actually used.  (assuming the `getGameModel()` gets the singleton instance)

Explaining: The `ObjectInputStream` will instantiate and deserialize a new instance of `GameModel`, then call `readResolve()`, which if your current implementation will tell the stream to use the old singleton instead.

If that's what you are trying to do, you should also consider writing an empty [`writeObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#a861) to avoid writing unnecessary data to the stream.

If that was not what you had in mind and `GameModel` is really supposed to be a singleton your choices are:

1. Using `readResolve()` to copy data from the "just read game model" to the singleton
2. Using `readResolve()` to replace the current singleton instance (sounds dangerous)
3. Any number of tricks with [writeReplace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#a5324)/[readResolve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a5903) using a replacement object (like `GameModelReplacement`) to hold the data you want to save/restore;

---

About `readObject()`: It's not clear in your question if that readObject is in `GameModel`. I'm assuming it's not. However if it is, the statement `(GameModel) inbos.readObject();` makes no sense as the GameModel is the current object (`this`). If that's the case do something like this:

```
public class GameModel {

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inbos) throws IOException {
       // do nothing
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOuputStream out) throws IOException {
       // do nothing
    }

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        // discarding serialized gamemodel, and using the singleton.
        return getGameModel();
    }
}
```